# Hiding navigation bar on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

guys, could anyone please help me with hiding navigation bar on Android 5.1.1 & Kivy 1.9.1? I thought that the fullscreen mode (Window.fullscreen = 'auto') will solve that problem, but it didn't.

Comment: Did you try Window.fullscreen = 1 ?

Comment: Yes I did. No effect

Comment: Have you tried changing `fullscreen = 0` to `fullscreen = 1` in the `buildozer.spec` file? This worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for the same thing, I found the gist below.  It uses Pyjnius.

- https://gist.github.com/rnixx/add38d808b5a8ad73947
- https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Code from gist:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger

try:
    from jnius import autoclass
    from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

    android_api_version = autoclass('android.os.Build$VERSION')
    AndroidView = autoclass('android.view.View')
    # AndroidPythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
    AndroidPythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')

    Logger.debug(
        'Application runs on Android, API level {0}'.format(
            android_api_version.SDK_INT
        )
    )
except ImportError:
    def run_on_ui_thread(func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            Logger.debug('{0} called on non android platform'.format(
                func.__name__
            ))
        return wrapper


class MyApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        self.android_set_hide_menu()

    def on_resume(self):
        self.android_set_hide_menu()

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def android_set_hide_menu(self):
        if android_api_version.SDK_INT >= 19:
            Logger.debug('API >= 19. Set hide menu')
            view = AndroidPythonActivity.mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(
                AndroidView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                AndroidView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                AndroidView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                AndroidView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                AndroidView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                AndroidView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
)
```

Comment: Interesting, mine didn't work until I changed renpy to kivy, see above.